# How to add contract to a Mist account without GUI?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, mist, contract-deployment

I'm new to Ethereum. I've followed a tutorial to deploy my contract by using web3.js and solc, then I got the abi and contract address. I'm thinking how I can add the contract to my Mist account through the code or command instead of opening Mist GUI to add it manually? I'll appreciate any help with this situation.